# Searching a std::Map

Tags: c++

What is the best way to search a std::Map for a specific key and value? Which basically means that I would like to find if exists a std::pair with key and value specified by me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
auto piter = m_mMap.find(iKey);

return pIter != m_mMap.end() && pIter->second == myvalue;
```

Answer (score 5):

Since `std::map` is keyed uniquely, you only have to look for the key using `find()` and you'll have found the only instance, you can then compare your value against the one you find to check if the values compare favourably.

Don't make the mistake of using `operator[]` which will insert the value or replace it if it doesn't exist - probably not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

std::map is a unique associative container, meaning that no two elements have the same key.

Thus, it suffices searching for the specific key by std::map::find.

Answer (score 0):

For finding items on some criteria on values I usually use predicate functors with the `std::find_if` function.

```
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

typedef std::map<int,std::string> MyMap;
typedef std::pair<int,std::string> MyPair;

struct Predicate
{
    Predicate(const MyPair& myPair):m_myPair(myPair)
    {
    }

    bool operator() (const std::pair<int,std::string> aPair)
    {
        return aPair.first == m_myPair.first && aPair.second == m_myPair.second;

    }

    MyPair m_myPair;
};


void Test()
{
    MyMap myMap;

    MyPair aPair(0,std::string("aTest"));
    Predicate predicate(aPair);

    MyMap::iterator iter = std::find_if(myMap.begin(),myMap.end(),predicate);
}
```

Comment: Be careful that by doing this you use a linear search in O(n) whereas using std::map::find is in O(log n).

Comment: Your are completely right, but if the criteria is only based on the value: this is the way of doing things. At first I just thought about the value criteria... it's ssegvic's remark that made me see that my solution was a little too much. But for learning purpose, I think it's goodhe might know more complex searches can be done this way.